# Multi-tenancy in JMS

Tags: jms, mq

I have been looking for a multi-tenant JMS provider that supports complete isolation of clients and integrates with WSO2. I have scratched around with Apache ActiveMQ for the last couple of weeks and realized that there may not be any support for multi-tenancy in ActiveMQ.

Which other JMS providers can give this? Also which version of JMS supports multi-tenancy?

Answer (score 3):

JMS is an API and is not designed explicit for multi tenancy. Authentication is done using either simple user/password or some certificate based negotiation.

That does not say multi-tenancy is not supported. However, most brokers requires you to create another broker instance that listen to a port per tenant - (IBM WebSphere MQ, Apache ActiveMQ on Debian/Linux, Apache Artemis, and more). This ensures complete isolation, but requires some manual steps to setup each tenant. There is no way to have 100+ tenants per server with this approach (or prove me wrong!)

You can likely setup some system that simulates tenants using prefixed usernames or similar, but that won't be a real multi-tenant broker.

Comment: the only thing i would add to this is that you can have the net effect of multi-tenancy with RabbitMQ vhosts. use a separate vhost for each client, and you are good to go. this is the equivalent of having one database per client, instead of a shared database between them all. each vhost is on the same server, but access by name specifically for each client

Comment: This looks interesting. It will take sometime for me to explore this fully. I am pretty much new in MQ

Comment: We are now looking at RabbitMQ with vHosts for foolproof multi-tenancy with exhaustive data insularity.<br/> Thanks for the answers. We will reach PoC stage after some months. Hope to dig deep into this then.

Comment: @SujithBabu what were your findings from PoC and which approach you went with ultimately?

Comment: @Kainix Nice to some traction 5 years after the original post. Finally I selected rabbit mq  This had vhost per client as mentioned by Derick Bailey and that was close to multi tenancy for us

Comment: @SujithBabu seems like RabbitMQ is the best choice for this even today.

Comment: Multitenancy doesnt mean Multi-instance : Here you are talking about isolation - so this is more about multi-instance design. Now how can you manage JMS and a multi-port or multivHost broker ?